# how to show rich formatted text in textarea

Tags: flex3, formatting, richtextbox, textarea

I have a form that uses Richtexteditor of Flex3 to write in their reply. The reply is then posted to a textarea, where all of the formatting is lost! I have embedded the font since I was doing some tweeening on the text boxes.
I need to find out how keep the formatting intact in the textarea from richtexteditor! 
has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you set the htmlText property on the TextArea, not just text.

Comment: thank josh, 
but i dont get it, what I dont have any htmltext, I just have normal text is being typed into Richtexteditor, and then later I take its contents and write them to a TextArea, but during the process formatting is lost! :(

Comment: .text returns the contents without any html markup included.  .htmlText returns the contents with html mark up.  Try out htmlText to see what I mean.

Comment: thanks a lotttttt man! 
that really helped! 
but now I have problem with embedding! 
if I don't embed the text wont "appear" with the panel. If i do embed the text then the text wont appear at all!

Comment: You'll have to be a little more specific.  I'm not sure what you mean by "embedding".  Maybe update your question with some sample code?

Comment: So.. here goes:
if i comment out this line:
//this.body.setStyle("fontFamily" , "regularFont");
then the showeffect doesn't apply to the font! 
it appears in perfect formatting but it doesn't fade in with the rest of the TextArea! it just appears!

Comment: Sorry Ali, I'm still not sure what you mean.  You have a different problem with animation and fonts?  Maybe start another question with more code?

Comment: ok I will thank you so very much! 
cheers! 

I hereby pronounce this thread dead :P